# not working Heartbeat in cron job

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

my magento website cron job not working ..
what problem ? i use A2 Hosting..

This is my Cron job setting in A2 Hosting C panel

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   php /home/microwave/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
*   *   *   *   *   /home/microwave/public_html/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 
*   *   *   *   *   sh /home/microwave/public_html/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 *   *   *   *   /home/microwave/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 *   *   *   *   php -f /home/microwave/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and my magento setting ..

[image]

**No heartbeat task found  error** <-AOE Error Message
not automatically to run heartbeat. only passively run
please help me

Comment: Are you using the AOE scheduler as well as the Magento cron? You should use one or the other. Check the /tmp directory on your server - that's where the scheduler lock folder is created. If it exists, delete it, flush your schedules and generate them again

Comment: @RobbieAverill i'm using Magento Default system Cron and AOE scheduler. but Magento Cron off is make error in AOE. "Scheduler is disabled in configuration (system/cron/enable). No schedules will be executed. " <- This is error message .

Comment: The AOE Scheduler has a menu item with instructions how to set up your cronjob. Follow these and remove all lines with cron.php and cron.sh